# How to access Heroku default.conf file to disable directory browsing

Tags: heroku, config, heroku-toolbelt

I'm using Heroku and want to access and modify the default.conf file to disable the directory browsing.  Does anyone know about Heroku and how to get to this file and edit it?  Thanks.